# Google Maps APi , how to insert multiple dynamic markers when user moves within the map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We have a requirement of displaying multiple pin markers on google map. The pin markers will be based on some addresses fetched from DB when user do a search. I know how to display multiple pin makers on google map, which is pretty trivial. On search we will have a couple of addresses, will get the lat long of those addresses and will create a list of map objects to display on map.

But the non trivial part is, we also want that when user moves within the map, dynamically we search against the database and find new addresses based on user focus and display pin markers of those addresses on map.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have an event listener on the `bounds_changed`, `center_changed` or `dragend` events on the map object.  This then makes an AJAX request to a page on your server, passing it the new coordinates for the map center (for instance).  This page returns data about the markers, which you then re-plot.

Comment: this is the uncomplicated part, the real challenge is actually accurately searching for the right records in the database without the getBOunds tools that are provided on the client side.

Comment: Right... so without knowing what server-side language we're talking about, what SQL is used for the existing address query or what the client-side javascript currently looks like, what do you suggest?

Comment: Only suggesting that a perfect algorithm to replicate the getBounds logic on the server with the pacific tilt and a few other factors is hard to find, not disputing the merit in your answer in any way. :)